# Single conda environment missing from jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

In my current conda environment I want to start using jupyter. I have done this successfully in other projects. This time I'm unable to access the kernel from jupyter.

The environment is activated using `conda activate myenv`.

The I run,
`(myenv) jupyter lab`,
which opens jupyter, but my kernel is not on the list.

I went back to an old environment: `(myenv) conda deactivate` then `conda activate oldenv`. There I installed the ipykernel using `(oldenv) conda install ipykernel`.

This kernel is now on the dropdown list of kernels when starting jupyter regardles of which jupyter i start. This means I can find it using both `(myenv) jupyter lab` and  `(oldenv) jupyter lab`.

I have tried to reinstall `nb_conda` and `ipykernel` in `myenv`. Now I'm out of ideas. Some outputs from `myenv` is listed below. I'm at such a loss I don't even know what the relevant output is.

```
(myenv) jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /anaconda3/envs/gkn-phase-two/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

```
(myenv) conda list | grep nb_conda*
nb_conda                  2.2.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
nb_conda_kernels          2.2.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
```

```
(myenv) conda list | grep ipykernel
ipykernel                 5.1.0           py36h24bf2e0_1002    conda-forge
```

```
conda list | grep jupyter*
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.5.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.2.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.4                 py36_1000    conda-forge
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.35.4                   py36_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to access several kernels with jupyter(-lab). To achieve this I install on the base conda jupyter(-lab) and for every env i do

```
source activate my_env
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "my_env"
```

Then from a terminal, and without enter on any env, I just need to launch jupyter(-lab) and select the favorite kernel for my notebook.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed the last line

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name gkn-phase-two --display-name "gkn-phase-two"` 

Could you explain what the line does? I have never needed to execute that command before, is there a reason I need it in this particular environment?

Comment: @haugstve the line is adding your kernel to the list of jupyter kernels. I do so for every environment I use. Probably you didn't realize before cos you where launching jupyter from the environment.

Comment: Thank you! 

I'm stil not sure that the reason is the environment I'm lunching Jupyter from. I have never needed it before, see the oldenv example. I'll be keeping this as a trick if my environments start acting up in the future :D